# Calculating modulus varies the result with 0 at the beginning

Tags: java

I was implementing a code to calculate a modulus of a number.

Ex. 

`long n = 70464307456L; // input value
int res = n % 256;`

The result I got here was 0, which is expected.

The next input was `070464307467L` (this input had leading 0)
I was expecting to get the result as 11 for this input, but the result I got was 55.

But when removed the leading 0 from the input, the result was 11.

I did not understand this behavior when 0 is at the beginning.

Can someone please help me to understand?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `System.out.println(070464307467L);` to see what decimal number it represents

Answer (score 0):

When you place a leading zero on the long literal in Java, you are telling the compiler that you are writting an octal litteral.